# how go to another activity when click on item in custom listview?

Tags: android

how go to another activity when click on item in custom listview?
i implement more than way bout no results, i think there is some mistake in my code.

com_under xml
    when click on any item in custom list view does no

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
        private final String[] itemname;
        private final Integer[] imgid;
    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
            super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
            this.context=context;
            this.itemname=itemname;
            this.imgid=imgid;
        }
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+itemname[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return rowView;
                }
            };







<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

package com.example.asus.myapplication;

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class com_under extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list1;
        String[] itemname ={
                "COME 334-Network",
                "COME 438-Java Programming",
                "COME 334-Computer Games ",
                "COME 226-Data sturctures",
                "COME 223-Algorithms",
        };
    Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.netw,
                R.drawable.java,
                R.drawable.game,
                R.drawable.data_st,
                R.drawable.algorthim,
        };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_com_under);
        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toolbar my_toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        Intent searchintent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchintent.getAction())) {
            String query = searchintent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(com_under.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView mtext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.item1);
                            if (position == 0) {
                                //code specific to first list item
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(com_under.this, sign_in_screen.class);
                                startActivity(myIntent);

                            }

                }

            });}

                }









    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.side_screen, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have setOnItemClickListener on com_under Activity or

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+itemname[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return rowView;
                }
            };
```

on getView method. Both of them do not work so decide which one to use and delete the other one.

Comment: If you want to do at com_under, you have to use list1.setOnItemClickListener not list1.setOnClickListener, can you check it?

Comment: list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent;

        switch(position){
            case 0:
          intent = new Intent(com_under.this,side_screen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
            intent = new Intent(com_under.this,register_screen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

    }

    }

    });

                }